# How flexible are Protestants on the Baptismal formula?

Tags: baptism

In the news recently is how thousands of people are being baptized again because of an invalid wording from their priest, who said, "We baptize" instead of "I baptize."

https://religionnews.com/2022/02/26/priests-new-assignment-helping-those-he-invalidly-baptized/

What is the general Protestant view, of those who practice paedobaptism, regarding the recognition of a "We baptize" person coming into their congregation? Are there any denominational leaders stating that the “we baptize” formula is unacceptable? If not, why not?

Comment: I would think Protestant groups that see baptism as a means of grace will be more serious about the baptismal formula. It was very serious in Catholicism since baptism is the gateway to all other sacraments, and I think that's why it became news.  The correct formula is also the basis on whether the Catholic Church accepts Protestant's baptism.

Comment: Considering the Great Commission uses plural verbs I think a strong case can be made that baptisms can be validly performed by a group, not just individuals. Probably the bigger issue with this Catholic priest is that he used the plural to include spectators, rather than just those directly involved in the ritual. But some churches may see everyone present as being directly involved...

Comment: I think this question is too broad.

Comment: @LukeHill, I refined my question to take your critique into account.

Comment: The problem with GratefulDisciple's comment is that the only "correct formula" is for a person to love God with all their heart, mind, and soul; and love their neighbors.  Anyone who is worried about the formulation of the baptism liturgy should search their hearts and ask whether that is something they got from man, or from God?   God needs no formulas to be the Alpha and the Omega or to be the omnipotent being Christians are supposed to believe He is.  Baptism is important, but even baptism can be changed around and different words spoken so long as the intent is correct and true.

Answer (score 2):

Protestants as a group are extremely diversified - including everything from strict fundamentalists to very liberal theologians. Personally, I find the story about the Priest silly. God doesn't care about us saying things perfectly or making an honest mistake. He cares what is in people's hearts first and foremost.

Comment: Thank you. It's so simple. +1

Comment: That is the problem, what's in people's hearts (i.e. what are their intentions) for a diversified group who mainly believes in "one mediator" you'd want to be baptized In Christ, not in Tom, Dick and Harry.  "I" in the sentence, is not supposed to be the priest himself, but Jesus who is acting through him.  https://www.ncregister.com/blog/what-s-wrong-with-we-baptize   @rajesh, I think this is a little too simple

Comment: @PeterTurner You are getting too caught up in the semantics of what is being said (lip service) rather than what is being expressed through the symbolic act of baptism: repentance, the washing away of sin, dedicating to change ones ways, being reborn, etc. It is this spirit that is important in baptism - not in uttering the words precisely.

Comment: Well said, Mr. Williams

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to say it as a lifelong Lutheran is this:

If a person is very worried that whether the priest or minister used "I" or "We" when they were baptized, that person is thinking of Christianity as a superstition where things that are unconnected are linked without reason.  Such as, "Step on a crack - break your mother's back."  Nothing in Christianity should be treated as superstition because it is extremely consistent and elegantly connected across time and space.  Supernatural, sure, but not superstitious.

Don't sweat the small stuff.  God doesn't care (you can tell Him I said that).  And if it turns out that He really does care, then God isn't the being we've been told He is and isn't worthy of our worship.  Our love for God should never be pursuant to being told to love God, or because we fear that one misstep will send us to Hell.  If that was true, we wouldn't need faith or free-will, we could just do what we were told.  Protestants believe these things have been granted to all of mankind by God's love and grace, and while we can willingly reject them or deny that they exist, we can't possibly remove them from the picture by speaking the wrong word in a ceremony.  Only God can do that, and by the death and resurrection of Jesus, he has promised that He won't by giving us the keys to the Kingdom.

Q.E.D. God doesn't care if the priest said "I" or "We" and neither should anyone else.